# WPF/XAML: Adding an element to a dependency property of type list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

What I want is a dependency property that can hold a List of something. If there is no element, the list shall not be empty, but the dependency property shall be null.

Here is the definition:

```
public List<Element> Elements {
  get { return (List<Element>)GetValue(ElementsProperty); }
  set { SetValue(ElementsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ElementsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Elements", typeof(List<Element>), typeof(ParameterControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

When adding an element...

```
<controls:Knob.Elements>
    <controls:Element Position="50,0" Text="j"/>
</controls:Knob.Elements>
```

... I get this exception.

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ... "Elements" ist NULL.
```

If I replace "new PropertyMetadata(null)" by "new PropertyMetadata(new List())", it's working. But in this case the depencency property is not null, if there is no element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I replace "new PropertyMetadata(null)" by "new PropertyMetadata(new List())", it's working.

Then the default list will be shared among all instances of the control. If you want a default list, you should initialize the `List<Element>` in the constructor:

```
public class ParameterControl : Control
{
    public ParameterControl()
    {
        Elements = new List<Element>();
    }

    public List<Element> Elements
    {
        get { return (List<Element>)GetValue(ElementsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ElementsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ElementsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Elements", typeof(List<Element>), typeof(ParameterControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

}
```

This is how most collection dependency properties are implemented in WPF, i.e. they always return an actual collection object that may be empty.

Comment: This variant has the advantage that every ParameterControl get's is one list. But the initial problem, that there is an empty list instead of no list, when there are no elements in the list.

Comment: @be_mi: Yes. What's your point? This is how most collection dependency properties are implemented, i.e. they always return an object that may be empty.

Comment: How can Elements become null in this scenario? There a lots of ParameterControls, but only one or two get elements assigned. Thus, I don't want unnecessary objects to be created.

Comment: In what scenario? Of course it is `null` if you don't initialize it somewhere. And if the list of elements is "unnecessary", you might as well remove the property altogether. Like I said, collection dependency property always return a collection. They should never return null becauase then you can't populate them in XAML.

Comment: Ok, collection dependency propertys always return a collection and can never be null. This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: You would usually write `SetCurrentValue(ElementsProperty,  new List<Element>());` instead of `Elements = new List<Element>();` in order to be able to assign a value by a Setter in a default Style. May be less relevant for a collection-type property, but there could for example be a default Binding.